# Rendering error in android studio gradle related

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use this lib (tokenautocomplete) from splitwise.

I inserted it on my build.gradle and it synced normally.

But, when I try to use some dependency from this lib, like this for example:

```
    <com.tokenautocomplete.TokenCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I get the following rendering problem:

`Rendering Problems
 The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.tokenautocomplete.TokenCompleteTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.InstantiationException   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)`

I'm with this problem for a few hours, did my google searches and found nothing.

I would like some help.

By the way, my dependencies in my build.gradle look like this:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0"
compile "com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.+"
compile "com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:2.0.0"
compile "com.splitwise:tokenautocomplete:2.0.2@aar"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0"
compile "com.android.support:design:23.0.1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `TokenCompleteTextView` in the library you are using is not properly configured to support Android Studio's preview.

The view will (presumably) still work fine if you run your app on a device or the emulator.

If you want support for Android Studio's preview pane, you should file a bug with the library's author.